# multipart File uploads using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, drag-and-drop, multipartform-data, dropzone.js

I am having troubles getting file uploads to work with NodeJS.  I am using Dropzone.JS to create a form that sends a POST request to /file-upload here:

```
<form action="/file-upload" class="dropzone dragndrop" id="my-awesome-dropzone"></form>
```

Then I have a route in app.js:

```
app.post('/file-upload', routes.upload);
```

Then my handler:

```
exports.upload = function(req, res){
     console.log(req.files);
     res.send("OK");
}
```

However, the upload function here is never called. The server crashes with this error first:

```
events.js:69
        throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                       ^
Error: Invalid data
    at WriteStream._write (fs.js:1616:31)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:265:14)
    at WritableState.onwrite (_stream_writable.js:94:5)
    at fs.js:1628:5
    at Object.wrapper [as oncomplete] (fs.js:475:5)
    at process._makeCallback (node.js:321:24)
```

So I am not sure what I should do because it appears that this is not my fault. I followed other tutorials and saw nothing wrong. Also, when I inspect my Network under chrome dev tools, it shows:

```
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/file-upload
**Request Headers**
Accept:application/json
Cache-Control:no-cache
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryMmLSkbfQskfIcjfE
Origin:http://localhost:3000
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:3000/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/537.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/24.0.1312.52 Safari/537.17
X-File-Name:Screenshot from 2013-03-20 12:23:42.png
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
**Request Payload**
------WebKitFormBoundaryMmLSkbfQskfIcjfE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Screenshot from 2013-03-20 12:23:42.png"
Content-Type: image/png


------WebKitFormBoundaryMmLSkbfQskfIcjfE--
```

Comment: It appears like there is no binary data actually being transfered.

Comment: what is your node version ? can you tell the file (name and location) which has your handler you call from app.js and how are you parsing the form data ? `req.files` requires expressjs

Comment: the handler is in model.js, which is where all my model related handlers are held. I have expressJS

Answer (score 17, accepted):

@user568109 and @nick-fishman are correct; you should use the bodyParser middleware for this.

Please see the sample code for a basic file upload form below. (Note: you will need to create an "uploads" directory to store the files.)

**file-upload.js**:

```
var express = require("express"),                                                                
    app = express();                                                                             

// tell express to use the bodyParser middleware                                                 
// and set upload directory                                                                      
app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: "uploads" }));                     
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);                                                   

app.post("/upload", function (request, response) {                                               
    // request.files will contain the uploaded file(s),                                          
    // keyed by the input name (in this case, "file")                                            

    // show the uploaded file name                                                               
    console.log("file name", request.files.file.name);                                           
    console.log("file path", request.files.file.path);                                           

    response.end("upload complete");                                                             
});                                                                                              

// render file upload form                                                                       
app.get("/", function (request, response) {                                                      
    response.render("upload_form.jade");                                                         
});                                                                                              

app.listen(3000);
```

**views/upload_form.jade**:

```
doctype 5
html
    head
        title Upload Form
    body
        h1 Upload File
        form(method="POST", action="/upload", enctype="multipart/form-data")
            input(type="file", name="file")
            input(type="submit")
```

Comment: request returns an array of files so try. console.log("files", request.files); Thanks for the great answer. Worked like a charm.

Comment: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/wiki/Connect-3.0 express.bodyParser is depricated

Comment: @robert mitchell I have trouble related to this issue but on multer framework https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63218454/how-can-we-send-data-in-mysql-when-the-form-has-set-to-enctype-multipart-form-d/63232322#63232322

Answer (score 2):

@user568109 is correct: you need ExpressJS and bodyParser enabled. Do you have a line similar to the following in your configuration?

```
app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: '/my/files' }));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try use busboy-body-parser to retrieve the request body parameters and the files.

```
start.js
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var busboyBodyParser = require('busboy-body-parser');


// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());


//parse multipart/form-data    
app.use(busboyBodyParser());



controllers/someController.js
someAction: function(req,res){
     if(req.method == "POST"){
           res.end(JSON.stringify(req.body)+JSON.stringify(req.files));
     }
}
//{"text":"testx"}{"anexo":{"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":.... }}} 
//req.body = {"text":"testx"}
//req.files = {"anexo":{"data":{"type":"Buffer","data":.... }}} 


views/someController/someAction.html
<form method="post" id="multipart" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" id="text1" name="text" value="testx" />
    <input type="file" id="anexo" name="anexo"  />
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
```

To create a file uploaded, you need work if the stream, for example:

```
/* file props
{  
   "data":{"type":"Buffer","data":.... },
   "fieldname":"anexo",
   "originalname":"images (1).jpg",
   "encoding":"7bit",
   "mimetype":"image/jpeg",
   "destination":"c:\\live\\sources\\uploads\\",
   "filename":"eventclock_images(1)_1443706175833.jpg",
   "path":"c:\\live\\sources\\uploads\\eventclock_images(1)_1443706175833.jpg",
   "size":9986
}
*/

var fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(file.path);
fileStream.write(file.data);
fileStream.end();

fileStream.on('error', function (err) {
    //console.log("error",err);
});
fileStream.on('finish', function (res) {
    //console.log("finish",res);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, if you want to answer to a question, then you should consider the case of the questioner.

Answer (score 0):

Most recent up-to-date version:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');


// serve your HTML form
app.use(express.static('public'));


// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// parse multipart/form-data
app.use(multer({dest:__dirname+'/uploads/'}).any());


app.post("/upload", function (request, response) {
    // request.files will contain the uploaded file(s),
    // keyed by the input name (in this case, "file")

    // show the uploaded files
    console.log("file name", request.files);

    response.end("upload complete");
});

app.listen(3000, "0.0.0.0");
```

npm install express --save

npm install body-parser --save

npm install multer --save