# enctype="multipart/form-data" always return null input but it is a must for multer to work how can we fix this?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, multer

Good day everyone,

I want to use this [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) framework for my input which has an image to be uploaded to my project file directory and sending the image file name to mysql database but enctype="multipart/form-data" returns my inputs to null and enctype="multipart/form-data" is a must for multer to work. I can't find relevant issue like mine I need your help guys.

[image]
[image]

> music_index.ejs

```
<form class="add-music-form" action="/save" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="song-featured-image">
            <input style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/*" id="file" name="featured_img"  onchange="loadFile(event)" required>
            <img id="output" class="image-preview" width="130" src="/img/rock-on.jpg" />
            <label for="file" class="attach_file" style="cursor: pointer">
            <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <a onclick="cancel()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
        </div>
</form>
```

> app.js

```
app.post('/save', (req, res) => {
    upload(req, res, (err) => {
      if(err){
        res.render('music_index', {
          msg: err
        });
      } else {
        if(req.file == undefined){
          res.render('music_index', {
            msg: 'Error: No File Selected!'
          });
        } else {
          res.render('music_index', {
            msg: 'File Uploaded!',
            file: `uploads/${req.file.filename}`
          });
        }
      }
    });

    let data = {
        featured_img: req.body.featured_img, 
        title: req.body.title, 
        band_name: req.body.band_name,
        audio: req.body.audio 
    };
    
    let sql ="INSERT INTO music SET ?";
    let query = connection.query(sql, data,(err, results) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

## opinion

try  req.body-> req.file

```
let data = {
        featured_img: req.file.featured_img, 
        title: req.file.title, 
        band_name: req.file.band_name,
        audio: req.file.audio 
    };
```

Comment: now it has this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'featured_img' of undefined

Comment: @exe maybe req.file->req.file.filename

Comment: @exe [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16534892/multipart-file-uploads-using-nodejs)  featured_img is in req.files.featured_img.. I guess